# HELM Install for custom Splunk configmap in NGINX

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

I'm new to Kubernetes and Helm. I have a requirement to use custom configmap for nginx so the Splunk team can get what they want.
I created the configmap for the custom error reporting to splunk. I'm told we use Helm but I'm not understanding the syntax.

Is it as simple as
`helm install nginx-config.yaml`

Comment: I also found this but I'm not really sure what information is needed for all the flags. 

helm install --name ingress --namespace ingress-nginx --set rbac.create=true,controller.kind=DaemonSet,controller.service.type=ClusterIP,controller.hostNetwork=true stable/nginx-ingress

Comment: Splunk Connect for Kubernetes supports installation using Helm. Read the Prerequisites and Installation and Deployment [documentation](https://github.com/splunk/splunk-connect-for-kubernetes) before you start your deployment of Splunk Connect for Kubernetes. Refer to this document for [Splunk configuration in NGINX](https://splunk.github.io/splunk-operator/Ingress.html#configuring-ingress-using-kubernetes-ingress-nginx) , [Configuration for Helm](https://docs.splunk.com/Observability/gdi/opentelemetry/kubernetes-config.html)

Comment: Is the above information is usefull, let me know to guide you further?

Comment: @HemanthKumar its work in progress. The more I read the more confused I get. I'm hoping there is something I'm missing that will make it make sense soon.

Comment: Have You got what you missed? Is my comment helped you to find any information?

Answer (score 0):

Helm is not the same as kubectl. For a helm chart, you’d create a template with variables that are typically populated by a values file. All in yaml syntax. I suggest you go through the helm QuickStart https://helm.sh/docs/intro/quickstart/

Then take a look at some repos for applications you may be familiar with. I used nginx as my learning repo https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/charts/ingress-nginx